# NoClassDefFoundError: org/kitesdk/morphline/api/MorphlineCompilationException

Tags: apache, maven, solr

I,m working on Apache Flume with MorphlineSolr as sink. Where my flume.conf file looks like:

```
a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSolrSink
a1.sinks.k1.morphlineFile = /etc/flume-ng/conf/morphline.conf
```

After running the flume command, I,m getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kitesdk/morphline/api/MorphlineCompilationException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSink.start(MorphlineSink.java:93)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I added the jar file from following repository:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ckite-morphlines-core

After this it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.FaultTolerance.parseRecoverableExceptionClassNames(FaultTolerance.java:118)
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.FaultTolerance.<init>(FaultTolerance.java:56)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineHandlerImpl.configure(MorphlineHandlerImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineSink.start(MorphlineSink.java:97)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any suggestions, would be of great help..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom application use a fat jar . Build a pom file and include the libraries

eg
file pom.xml (of your project)

org/apache/solr/**
.
.